# Angular Material 15 - change form field size

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

i upgraded my app to angular 15 and angular material 15, and now iam not able to change form field size. In previous versions of angular material form field adjusts its size according to font-size, in version 15 this doesnt work anymore.
Any ideas how to solve this in version 15?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust material form field by adding below CSS

```css
mat-form-field {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).